# Windows: Get absolute path of junctioned folder

Tags: windows, junction, ntfs-junction

System: Windows 10x64pro
I have a folder junctioned into another. However, once inside the junctioned folder, I need to be able to get its actual absolute path. How is this done?

Come to think of it, could I write a C++ app that pulls the directory entry for "." or another file inside and get the actual absolute path that way?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Mike Russinovich at MS SysInsternals already solved this with the [Junction](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/junction) tool. Passing the junctioned-folder as the only parameter reveals its actual location.

```
junction C:\MyJunctionedFolder
```

(It gives more information than I need, but I can figure out a script to trim it down for use in the script I actually need this for.)